# Dymola - setting the display window as tiled as default

Tags: dymola

It is extremely useful to have the Modelica Text, Diagram and Documentation on the same view in Dymola. This can be achieved by selecting Window>Tile Windows or `Cntrl + Shift + T` . However if another model on a separate tab is selected, the the tiled window arrangement is lost and can only be restored manually using the methods mentioned above.

[image: Tiled Dymola Layout]

Is there a setting to make all components be displayed as tiled by default so they maintain this layout when browsing through multiple tabs?